# Can you disable the next and prev buttons in the Android browser?

Tags: android, html, browser, drop-down-menu, picker

The menu that opens in the native Android browser when my dropdowns (select tags) are clicked features prev. and next buttons. When I click them nothing happens. Is there any way to disable these? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: FWIW, I have never seen that in any Android browser.

Comment: If you can post the code, that can help us to help you.

Comment: @CommonsWare I see it in nearly every native Android browser. Particularly version 4.2.2- T310UEUAMH2 on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 3. There is no code really, just a standard select tag with options, happens everywhere. Thanks.

Comment: "I see it in nearly every native Android browser" -- add a short URL in your question to some page that, in your opinion, will always generate these buttons.